# What flags can I use to add methods to controller in artisan:make controller?

Tags: laravel

I am curious about the `php artisan make:contorller myController` command. I am using Laravel 5.7.* and I know that we can add flags to that command, but I do not know what are those flags; for example, a flag to add all CRUD methods. How many flags are for this make:controller command? What are those flags? All of the flags works for all the laravel versions (version 5)?

Comment: `--all` `-a` =  Generate a migration, factory, and resource controller for the model.
`--controller` `-c` = Create a new controller for the model.
`--factory` `-f`  = Create a new factory for the model.
`--force`          Create the class even if the model already exists.
`--migration` `-m`  = Create a new migration file for the model.
`--pivot` `-p`  =  Indicates if the generated model should be a custom intermediate table model.
`--resource` `-r` =  Indicates if the generated controller should be a resource controller. **yes, flags works for laravel 5 and higher version**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`php artisan help make:controller` ... enjoy

Answer (score 1):

You can use following flags:

- --all -a        Generate a migration, factory, and resource controller for the model.
- --controller -c  Create a new controller for the model.
- --factory -f     Create a new factory for the model.
- --force          Create the class even if the model already exists.
- --migration -m   Create a new migration file for the model.
- --pivot -p       Indicates if the generated model should be a custom intermediate table model.
- --resource -r    Indicates if the generated controller should be a resource controller.